# Using NAND flash dump with OOB data

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, flash, memory-dump

I have NAND flash memory dump, as a separate MTD partitions copied from NAND flash chip use built-in nanddump commands. I need to reflash some corrupted MTD partitions. In order to reflash partitions properly, should I use the partition dump that contain only the *actual data*, cleaned first from OOB data dummy chunks?

Answer (score 1):

This depends very much on how exactly you plan to write the data back; some options would accept only "payload", others may need OOB too.

If you use U-Boot's `nand write`, it seems it accepts data without OOB but [you need to erase target pages manually first](https://elinux.org/Didj_U_Boot_Flashing_Primer).

Comment: I used U-boot built-in commands `nand erase` and `nand write`. Before flashing I used python script to process dump and separate the actual data from OOB data. The test was unsuccessful, when I tried write data, an error was shown `Attempt to write non page aligned data. 13548080 bytes written: ERROR`. Before this I tried also write raw partition dump (with OOB), but linux kernel didn't loaded, not sure what was wrong with my dump.

Comment: @minto maybe this will help https://e2e.ti.com/support/legacy_forums/embedded/linux/f/354/t/48176?Unable-to-boot-from-kernel-stored-in-NAND-Flash

Comment: Cleaned dump is 13548080 bytes in size. NAND device have `Block size 16384, page size 512, OOB size 16 bytes`. 13548080 bytes is incomplete 26462 pages. A complete 26462 pages is 26462 x 512 = 13548544 bytes. The difference is 464 bytes: so need I append these 464 bytes for the complete page?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. For example Samsung XSR stores information about the blocks in spare area, thus you need to have to dump both data and spare.